# shell script :: addition of two hexa-decimal numbers

Tags: shell

```
#!/system/bin/sh

OTG0_V_SYNC=`smn 0x00013fbc`
OTG0_V_SYNC=${OTG0_V_SYNC:11}
echo $OTG0_V_SYNC

OTG0_V_BLANK=`smn 0x00013fdc`
OTG0_V_BLANK=${OTG0_V_BLANK:11}
echo $OTG0_V_BLANK

OTG0_V_ACTIVE=$(( $OTG0_V_SYNC + $OTG0_V_BLANK ))
echo "$OTG0_V_ACTIVE"
```

On running this shell script , getting following error.

```
$ ./test.sh                                                                                                                
00000df7
00060000
./test.sh[19]:  00000df7 + 00060000 : bad number '00000df7'
```

Though sometime when register values are non-aplha numeric then it works.

```
$ ./test.sh                                                                                                                
00060000
00060000
00120000
```

Comment: apparently your `/system/bin/sh` cannot do arithmetic on hex numbers

Comment: @AbhiKhar : You can use i.e. `bc` or `dc` to do hex-arithmetic. Also, if you use the Z-shell as your shell, you can do it natively (see the section _ARITHMETIC EVALUATION_ in the _zshmisc_ man page. Or you switch to a completely different programming language, such as Ruby or Perl.